# RewriteRule / HTTP auth for one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, url-rewriting, vhosts

I want to redirect "?p_id=62" to http authentification but it does not work.

**my conf:**

```
<LocationMatch  ^/>
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^\?p_id=62$
   RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_AUTH:1,L]
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   AuthType basic
   AuthName "Auth Needed"
   AuthUserFile "/var/www/site/.htpasswd"
   Require valid-user
   Allow from env=NO_AUTH
   Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match the `?` part of the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p_id=62$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=NO_AUTH:1,L]
```

However, this is not going to work. The mod_auth modules are applied **before** mod_rewrite gets applied, so by the time the rewrite rule checks the query string to set the environment variable, mod_auth has already flagged the request as a 401 (needs auth). You might have to settle for a scripted solution, like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^\?p_id=62$
RewriteRule ^ /auth_script.php [L]

<Files "auth_script.php">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 AuthType basic
 AuthName "Auth Needed"
 AuthUserFile "/var/www/site/.htpasswd"
 Require valid-user
</Files>
```

and the `auth_script.php` will simply load the content at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` URI and return it to the browser (not redirect).